# Codepush React-Native android staging release

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to release the React-Native Android application using Microsoft's Codepush on staging for this have followed the given instruction on website and able to build the bundle file and release successfully on staging but didn't see the updated changes on mobile which I released.

Firstly I installed the application on mobile using usb (Run on device).

After that make some changes in application and release on staging using Codepush but when I am restarting the app on mobile is not showing the changes.

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#getting-started
Android Setup

app/build.gradle :-

```
defaultConfig : versionName: "1.0.0",

signingConfigs : release { storeFile file("my-release-key.keystore")
            storePassword "myapp"
            keyAlias "alias-key"
            keyPassword "myapp"
        }

buildTypes: signingConfig signingConfigs.release

dependencies: compile project(':react-native-code-push')
```

setting.gradle :-

```
include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
```

CLI command :-

```
react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output codepush.js --dev false;

code-push release App-Android codepush.js 1.0.0
```

I have installed the aap on mobile with versionName 1.0.0 and make some changes in application code and again build the bundle and release the app with version name 1.0.1.

Here I am not changing versionName in `buid.gradle` only changing the versionName in release command `code-push release App-Android codepush.js 1.0.1`

Should I need to change the versionName every time in `build.gradle` for new release and use the same in release command?

Can any one help please?
Thanks

Comment: Could you specify the CLI commands you used to build your JS bundle and then release it to CodePush? That will help identify what might be going on. Also, make sure that the binary version you are passing to the "code-push release" command is the exact same version that is specified in your RN Android app's build.gradle file. Not passing the right version number is a common reason for an update not being discovered from the running app.

Comment: @JonathanCarter Please review i have specified  the command  in question: Thanks

Comment: As the answers below mention, you don't need to change the version to "1.0.1" when you call "code-push release" unless you change the version in the build.gradle file to 1.0.1. In your example above, simply keep passing 1.0.0 to "code-push release" and everything will work as expected.

Comment: @JonathanCarter and Please specify how much time it will take to reflect the changes on users.

Comment: When you release an update via the CodePush CLI, it is available immediately. But the app still needs to call sync/checkForUpdate to discover it, so it will become available to your users as soon as the app does a sync with the server.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Suppose i make some changes in application like Text or color should it will reflect to user on release the updated bundle without make any changes in vesrionName .

Comment: Yes. You do not need to change the versionName. Simple release the updated bundle to CodePush specifying the exact same version value that you want to receive the update (e.g. 1.0.0)

Comment: Did you try this suggestion? Either of the answers below should fix your issue, so it would be great to confirm that and mark one :) If you have further questions, the a Discord channel might be a better place to chat.

Comment: @JonathanCarter yes i tried but not able resolve and somehow got react-native 0.18.0 so i am configuration the changes and soon update you. Thanks,

Comment: @JonathanCarter Thanks for help now  i am able to get the app changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact CLI commands you are using to bundle your JS and then release it to CodePush, it's hard to know exactly what might be going on, but there are a couple possibilities that you should double check you're doing correctly:

1. When you call the CodePush CLI's release command, make sure that you are passing a path to the JS bundle file as the contents of the update. Android doesn't currently support updating images, and therefore, it doesn't support being given a directory of files. If you tried releasing a directory, the CLI and server would allow it, but the plugin within the app would fail to install the new update when it syncs with the server, since it wouldn't understand the contents. This is a temporary limitation and will be addressed in an upcoming release of the plugin.
2. When you call the CodePush CLI's release command, make sure you are specifying the exact binary version of the app that the update should target. For Android, this is the android.defaultConfig.versionName property in your build.gradle file. If you're testing CodePush on a brand new project, this is likely "1.0.0", so just make sure you are passing this exact version to the release command. Otherwise, when the plugin attempts to sync with the server, it will think that the release isn't targeting it and won't attempt to install it.
3. Make sure that the deployment key you specified in your MainActivity file actually corresponds to York staging deployment. You can confirm this by running "code-push deployment ls" and comparing the key in your code with the key of your staging deployment.

You can find out more details about the release command, and the behavior of each parameter, by checking out the CLI docs: http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/docs/cli.html

If neither of those end up being your issue, it would be helpful if you could share the exact steps you're running to release an update, and also, take a look at the Chrome console (or logcat) and let us know what logging you're seeing. The CodePush plugin will report errors in configuration/etc. to help you diagnose them.

Comment: the above question steps are fine for codepush configuration only need to take care when we are changing in MainActivity.java class.

Answer (score 2):

I got error like you.

- check you bundle file
- check release command (code-push release YouApp your_bundle_file version)

  If you set in your `android.defaultConfig.versionName` is 1.0.20 so you need release like this:

  code-push release YouApp your_bundle_file 1.0.20

You need release version 1.0.20 until you change `android.defaultConfig.versionName` version(1.0.21) and after that you need release version 1.0.21.

Notice: the `version` in release command can not change until your application `android.defaultConfig.versionName` change.

Comment: What do you mean by "check your bundle file"? Mind to give more details about that?